# LED pasties, 3v circuit board lights

Tags: material-identification, electronics

[image]
Apologies for being a noob. This set (3v lithium battery, color interchanging light & circuit board) was taped inside my pasties. I had customized the front, and they were supposed to light up for an event. However, upon molding it to my body, one of the wires connecting the battery to the circuit board snapped. I have attempted to use E6000 glue to reattach but feel certain this is a bad idea. Can anyone please tell me if I can find this circuit board/battery set on Amazon, or do I need to buy the individual pieces and make this set myself? TIA. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the number visible in the photo, I discovered that the item is sometimes called a "disc golf light" and found that there are single LED and triple LED versions. You can use the same search terms to find a resource of your choosing.

I found an inexpensive US-based resource here:

[disc golf lights](https://www.extremeglow.com/store/p/27-Flat-Lights-2-Pack.aspx?gclid=EAIaIQobChMImfnexK6w3gIVl7rACh2fbQ9yEAQYASABEgIvk_D_BwE)

[image: disc golf lights]

Some of the search returns that reference Amazon result in a 404 error, others do not.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to fix my project. Thank you for your assistance Fred, I greatly appreciate it! 

Comment: I'm glad that it's the right stuff. Please pop a check mark on the answer if you believe it to be correct. I get a little electric shock with each check mark! Maybe I should check my wiring.

Comment: Haha! Done ✅ There are plenty of people who will be inadvertently thanking you for this!